# MS EXCEL column reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 sheets in excel, say sheet 1 & sheet 2. I have to update some data in sheet1, which calculates some values using formulas incorporated in sheet 1 itself.
I have sheet 2, where I need to update some of the values of sheet 1 for report generation. This is a daily job. Daily I will keep on updating values in subsequent rows in sheet 1 (only 1 row data will be filled in a day) & I have to change reference values in sheet 2. Say on day 1 I had entered data in row B1 and accordingly calculated values gets updated in say D2,L2 & P2 (in sheet 1. Now in sheet 2, i have to keep the output values of D2, L2 & P2 from sheet 1 in say, M12, R15, S32 in sheet 2. I want to keep a row number inserting cell in sheet 2, so that all values of sheet 2 having reference to single row of sheet 1 will be updated at once. 
Like, insert formula as ='Sheet1'Mx in sheet (x is row no. in Sheet 1)[image] 
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm not sure what your question is. I suggest you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52120990/edit) your question to clarify what the desired output is, what you've tried and where the problem is exactly.

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* 

Check out the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!) and see "[ask]" as well as **how to create a [mcve]**.  Also, here's a "perfect question" [checklist](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the sites' top user. It helps to make your question as direct and easy to read as possible - rather than s single huge paragraph and uncropped images.

Comment: Hi, I have to update data daily in say, column C in sheet 1. Based on the value I give, various values are generated in other columns in same sheet. I need to organize these values in a peculiar way in another sheet for generating a report. So, for day 1 I will be updating a value in say C6, next day I have to update in C7, then C8 and so on.  I want to give only reference row number in Sheet 2 so that report is automatically generated instead of me changing reference cell number in each cell in sheet number 2. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a dynamic formula into your Sheet2 cells E6, E9 and G7 using a dynamic formula. The formula should be able to modify itself based upon the contents of H2 in Sheet2.

This can be very easily done using an INDIRECT function.

In Sheet2, enter the below formulae in respective cells:

```
E6 is =INDIRECT("Sheet1!E"&H2)
E9 is =INDIRECT("Sheet1!H"&H2)
G7 is =INDIRECT("Sheet1!J"&H2)
```

Ref: https://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html for other examples and uses of INDIRECT.

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked perfectly 

Comment: @Vishnu, please accept the answer as it solved your problem

Comment: Done as per the details available in help section. Please inform if anything is pending. Thank you